# How to implement JWT token based authentication mechanism with Apache Shiro?

Tags: oauth, jwt, shiro

I have a web application in which Authorization is handled by Apache Shiro. Now we need to convert it to restful service and need to add an authentication mechanism . I am looking for a possibility to keep Shiro itself for authorization, so that code changes are minimal, and JWT for authentication. Please suggest me how can I achieve it. Is there any framework available for it?

Answer (score 2):

I made a library to achieve this.

https://github.com/panchitoboy/shiro-jwt

You only have to implement UserDefault and UserRepository with your bussines logic.

It's based on apache-shiro, i have created a filter based on the shiro AuthenticatingFilter.

Regards,